# ASP.NET Visual Studio doesn't capture changes - compiles from temporary files

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010, temporary-files

I'm designing Web Pages in ASP.NET with Visual Studio 2010. The compiler works from the temporary files of previous compilations. This means that each time that I make a change in my Css files, or changing the resource files I'm working with - VS compiles my webpage with the previous data.

I'm rather new to ASP.NET, and I'm sure there's something I'm missing here or unfamiliar with, because it is impossible to work fluently like this.

Only when I locate the temporary files, delete them, and recompile the project - only then it is working. But I have to be very careful which files I'm deleting.

Is there a way to overcome this problem? or to delete the proper files in a single command?

Help! :)

Comment: What type of project is it? Is it an ASP.NET web application or web site?

Comment: You are dealing with browser cache that has nothing to do with VS. If you are using IE (most likely) just hit CTRL+F5, this will force browser to refresh css files.

Comment: Does this happen in different browsers? Are you hosting the app in IIS or running it with VS?

Answer (score 0):

Few things I do to reflect the changes and not to see this problem.

1. Close cassini whenever you start new. A previous running instance of cassini often causes the error.
2. The first should work, in any case it does not than clear the browser cache. Stylesheets and Scripts are often cached by browsers.

A recommendation:- Try to run new instances of your app in private browsing. You will not see the problems you normally do when in private browsing.